# how to create textbox list control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a textbox for entering employeename.When an user types the employeename,i wanted to list all the employees from database starting with that typed letter,just like a dropdownlist

I dont want any third party control.Is there any easier and understandable way for doing this??

Comment: Take a look at AjaxToolkit Controls.

Comment: @ksg You will have to use javascript/Jquery Ajax to achieve this.A small idea.On every keypress event for your textbox you will need to call a Web Service which will return you the results matching the letter typed from your database and then display them.There are plenty of ready made controls for the same.

Comment: Can u explain how to done this by webservice.I've no idea abt webservice and it would be great if u could help me out from this hole...

Comment: @ksg Building your own will take a bit of work , are you fine using Jquery UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library it's very easy a with good code

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Firstly we will use **[Jquery UI Auocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)** that will consume `ASP.NET Web Service`

(Let's say `Name.asmx`).

Add reference to `Jquery UI CSS` file

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Now add reference to `Jquery library`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Add reference to the `Jquery UI`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Let's say you have a textbox with class `auto`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbAuto" class="auto" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Now we will write a script that will pass every single letter typed in the `textbox` to our `Web Service` `(Name.asmx)`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".auto").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Name.asmx/FetchNames",
                data: "{ 'name': '" + request.term + "' }",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                        return {
                            value: item.Name
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
});
</script>
```

Finally here is the `Web Service` in `C#`

```
[WebMethod]
public List<string> FetchNames(string name)
{
//Write your query to get names that begin with the letter passed as parameter and     return results
//Remember return the results by converting it to List.
}
```

Hope it will help.

Reply in case you have issues.

**EDITED:**

Here is the query.

```
SqlDataReader rdr = null;
SqlConnection con = null;
SqlCommand cmd = null;
List<string> empName=new List<string>();

            try
            {
                // Open connection to the database
                string ConnectionString = "server=yourservername;uid=sa;"+
                    "pwd=yourpswd; database=yourdatabase";
                con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                con.Open();

                // Set up a command with the given query and associate
                // this with the current connection.
                string CommandText = "SELECT FirstName" +
                                     "  FROM Employees" +
                                     " WHERE (FirstName LIKE +name%)";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(CommandText);
                cmd.Connection = con;


                // Execute the query
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                while(rdr.Read())
                {
                   empName.Add(rdr["FirstName"].ToString());
                }
              return empName;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // Print error message

            }
```

*Note:I have not tested this , but I think by doing few changes as per your needs it will work fine! Also try and improve this code*

Comment: I tried different methods for writing query in webservice but error came.I think writing query in webservice is in different way not as writing in sqlserver..Can you help me out in this case...                     [WebMethod]
public List<Name> FetchNames(string name)
{
//Write your query to get names that begin with the letter passed as parameter and     return results
//Remember return the results by converting it to List.
}

Comment: "Select * from tblSupplier where suppliername like "+name+%+""

Comment: @ksg Can you not use Linq or Lambda expression?

Comment: Sir frankly speaking im not used to  Linq or Lambda expression?That why i found it difficult to write the query

Comment: @ksg No issues I will try n post the query!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15734/discussion-between-ksg-and-freebird)

Comment: Yes i've written webservice as per ur updation,and its working fine when i tested the webservice...                                       I think the issue is in jquery..

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery autocomplete api :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#<%=ApplicationSearchResult.ClientID %>").autocomplete({ //applicationSearchResult is your textbox
  source: function (request, response) {
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "Dashboard.aspx/GetTreeNodesByText", // the function you have to call to bring you the data
   data: "{'text': '" + request.term + "'}", // the letter the user entered in the textbox
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (data) {
   response(data.d);
   }
   });
   },
   minLength: 1
   });
   });
```